# Common elements of muiltiple arrays but not using Lists

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way i could return in an array the common elements of 2 or more arrays? I know having some of the methods under lists could do it but is there a way to do it by only using arrays? I made my own get and length btw since i am creating a an array called OrderedIntList.

Example would be:

1,3,5

1,6,7,9,3

1,3,10,11

Result: 1,3

I tried this and it outputs the common elements between two arrays and not all. 
I know there's something wrong but i do not how to make it work like it suppose to work :(

//returns the common elements of inputted arrays

```
public static OrderedIntList common(OrderedIntList ... lists){ 

int[] list = new int[10];

for(int x = 1; x <= lists.length -1; x++){

  for(int q = 0; q < lists[0].length()-1; q++) {

    for(int z = 0; z < lists[x].length(); z++) {

      if (lists[0].get(q)==lists[x].get(z)){
         list[q] = lists[0].get(q);
                  }
              }
          }
      }

 OrderedIntList newlist = new OrderedIntList(list);     

 return newlist;
  }
```

Comment: your question is good, yet your code looks :(

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity - why do you want to avoid lists?

Comment: Your custom object won't be array-indexable.  You'll need to expose the underlying array before you can index into it.

Comment: Decompose your problem in smaller ones. Create a method `boolean isIntContainedInList(int i, OrderedIntList list)`. Then create a method boolean isIntContainedInAllTheLists(int i, OrderedIntList[] listArray), that uses the previous method. Those should be very simple methods, but once you have them, the algorithm becomes much easier to implement.

Comment: @Ant Veeranna probably because it's an homework :)

Comment: By *common elements*, you mean the elements which have the same value and location or just value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an easy algorithm to solve it...

> ```
>     1) Instantiate an instance variable of type array called
>     "commonElements" pointing to the elements of the first Array. At the
>     beginning these are your common elements.
>
>     2) Create a method call getCommonElements(int[] commonElements,
>     int[] newList). This method manipulates the commonElements array to leave 
>     it with only the common elements between the two. (p.s Use a temporary 
>     array to achieve this if you find it easier)
>
>     3) Iterate over all the arrays present in "lists" starting from the
>     second array.
>
>     4) call the method at point 2 for each array .
> ```

**All the difficult part for you it's to implement a method that given 2 arrays finds the common elements!**

Comment: @dj robles If you want to excel, remember than in an ordered array you can find if an element is present or not in logarithmic time. Keep it in mind when you implement the method at point 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.intersection(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)`

to get the intersection of two lists (elements presents in both lists)

And to pass your array as a Collection: java.util.Arrays.asList(Object[] a);

But working on arrays is tedious, at best. You should consider why you don't want to use a Collection...

Answer (score -1):

As a partial answer, you're probably doing too much work by fully reimplementing an OrderedIntList the way you're doing, since ArrayList and friends already come with sorting baked in via the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class.

```
import java.util.Collections;
public class OrderedIntList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
  @override // to effect sorted inserts
  public void add(Integer i) {
    this.add(i);
    Collections.sort(this);
    // done.
  }
}
```

Wanting to do this for pure arrays is a nice exercise, but then you'll be better of implementing sorting properly with a quick sort (you can't websearch for a java implementation of that without getting a million results) or an insert sort (equally websearchable), and follow the same recipe.

any time you push a number into the array:

1. guess where the number goes (although that's optional),
2. insert the number,
3. resort your array if you know your guess wasn't perfect.

Comment: Lists can't sort themselves.

Comment: oops, forgot to turn that into Collections.sort

Comment: I'm still not exactly sold on this being a good answer.  It seems like they want to do an N-way intersection to see the common elements.  A list does not seem like the appropriate data type for this.

Comment: yeah that's a fair point. I'll add a bit of text to mention this doesn't solve the original problem, but does address the orderedintlist they've showed trying to implement. (The question's kind of a two-in-one)